# Bitrise Google Play Deploy start failing, which used to work fine

Tags: bitrise

The logs around the error is this below. It used to work but after a few days ago, this start failing. I didn't not change deploy flow.

The only change is that we started to pay. Before that we used it as a trial member.
Though I don't think that is the cause...

Does anyone know how to get over this error?

```
Using app from: /Users/vagrant/deploy/app-production-[REDACTED]-bitrise-signed.apk
Configuration read successfully

Authenticating
Authenticated client created

Create new edit
 editID: xxxxxxx
Edit insert created

Upload apks or app bundles
Uploading /Users/vagrant/deploy/app-production-[REDACTED]-bitrise-signed.apk 1/1
Uploaded apk version: 36
Done uploading of 1 apps
New version codes to upload: 36
Applications uploaded

Update track
Release version codes are: [36]
alpha track will be updated.
 updated track: alpha
Track updated

Committing edit
Failed to commit edit, error: googleapi: Error 403: You cannot rollout this [REDACTED] because it does not allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs., forbidden

|                                                                              |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| x | google-play-deploy@3.6 (exit code: 1)                         | 19.44 sec|
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Issue tracker: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-google-play-deploy/issues |
| Source: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-google-play-deploy               |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```